# Why my animation with css : active is not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a button with send and on clicking, I want to move it, (this is just for asking) can you tell me why it is not working

This is the jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './home.css'
import sound from './sound.mp3'
import video from './A.mp4';
import img1 from './home1.jpeg';
import img2 from './home4.jpeg';
import img3 from './home3.jpeg';
import { useRef } from 'react';
 return (
        <>
<div className="form" onClick={prevent} >
                        <form action="" className='contact_form'>
                            <div className="heading_contact">
                                Get in touch with me
                            </div>
                            <input className="info_contact" placeholder='Your Name' ></input>
                            <input className="info_contact" placeholder='Your Email' ></input>
                            <textarea className='info_contact' name="" id="" cols="27" rows="10" placeholder='You message'></textarea>
                            <button id='delivery' className="submit"  >
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-truck" ></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <div className='alternates' >
                            Or contact me through
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

And this is the CSS for the animation

```
#delivery:active {
    position: relative;
    animation-name: delivery;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: 5;
    @keyframes delivery{
        from {
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
    
        to {
            margin-right: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to bring the keyframes section out of the `:active` selector but it still won't work.

Comment: I think your codesandbox link is wrong. Also you should really add code directly to your question here on stack overflow.

Comment: Please check now!!

Comment: Your CSS syntax is incorrect. Are you using some preprocessor? Please make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example